# How to change the repl prompt of node.js?

Tags: node.js

`node.js`'s default repl prompt is `>`, I sometimes type shell commands into it. In order to easily distinguish it from other programming language repl's and shell prompts, I would like to change it to something like `node >`. Is it possible, or is there any better practice on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a small node program which fires up a REPL and specifies `prompt: 'node >'` in the options hash.

See docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).

```
// repl.js
const repl = require('repl');
var replServer = repl.start({prompt: 'node > '});

$ node repl.js
node >
```